# Android Emulator error "Can't access SD card"

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm using the Android Emulator to test my app. I added [the cordova media capture plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) and am using the `captureAudio` method but in the Android emulator I cannot use it, because I get the following error (see screenshot):

`Can't access SD card.`

How do I test the Sound Recorder in the android emulator?

[image: Can't access SD card.]